# How to mock return value in another file?

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux, jestjs

I'm testing an actions file in flux with jest and can't seem to figure out how to mock a return value in it.

When I specify the return value (see code below) for a mocked module in my test file, everything works fine, but when that same function is called in the module I'm testing, it comes up as undefined.

```
#MissionActions-test.js

jest.dontMock('../MissionActions');
describe('MissionActions', function() {
    var GameStore = require(root + 'stores/game/GameStore');
    var MissionActions;

    beforeEach(function() {
        MissionActions = require('../MissionActions');
    });

    it('should...', function() {
        GameStore.getGame.mockReturnValue({test: "test"});
        console.log(GameStore.getGame()); // prints {test : "test"}
        MissionActions.addMissionFromBank();
    });
});
```

And MissionActions.js which is being tested.

```
# MissionActions.js
var GameStore = require('../../stores/game/GameStore');

var MissionActions = {
    addMissionFromBank: function(bankMission) {
        var game = GameStore.getGame();
        console.log(game); // prints undefined
    }
}

module.exports = MissionActions;
```

My interpretation of the API & automatic mocking is that setting mockReturnValue on a mocked module (in this case GameStore) applies throughout the test, not just within the test file.

How would would I go about mocking the GameStore.getGame() method so that it applies within MissionActions.js as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've run into this before as well.

The fix is, in your test, move the GameStore require into the beforeEach block.

```
beforeEach(function() {
    MissionActions = require('../MissionActions');
    GameStore = require(root + 'stores/game/GameStore');
});
```

I'm not 100% sure on this, but I believe the mockRegistry is scoped per test. So when you require it just inside of the describe block, it mocks it like you would expect.  Then, when you require MissionActions inside of the beforeEach, it starts a new scope.  So it mocks MissionActions, then starts to mock it's dependencies and does a brand new mock of GameStore.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much. I can't believe it was that simple.

Comment: no it was not simple. and i had the same issue in my tests. If you are using babel with imports this stuff is a killer. Jest in my opinion lacks a lot of details in documentation. anyway @Crob Good response.